# Query in spring data Jpa multiple condition

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The result sql should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM items where id LIKE '%"+ key + "%' or name LIKE '%"+ key + "%'";
```

here key is variable.I need to do this sql in spring data jpa.

I try like below and code is not working

```
@Transactional
public List<Item> findItemNameOrId(String key) {
    return  itemRepository.findByItemNameOrIdContaining(key);       
}
```

this is ItemRepository

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer> {

List<Item> findByItemNameOrIdContaining(String key);
}
```

Comment: Please add the query generated by your method.

Comment: And you can allways add a `@Query("select * from items where id like %?1% or name like %?1%");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this and it should run

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer> {

@Query("SELECT i FROM items i where i.id LIKE %:key% or i.name LIKE %:key%")
    List<Item> findByItemNameOrIdContaining(@Param("key") String key);
}
```